# Qt double buffering behaviour

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I am converting some code from using QWidget to QOpenGLWidget, I want to use double buffering to render the widget, so far:

```
    void clsElevStrip::initializeGL() {
        qDebug() << "clsElevStrip::initializeGL()";
        initializeOpenGLFunctions();
    //Get the openGL context
        mpobjContext = context();

        if ( mpobjContext != NULL ) {
    //Setup surface
            mobjFormat.setDepthBufferSize(24);
            mobjFormat.setSamples(4);
            mobjFormat.setVersion(3, 0);
            mobjFormat.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::NoProfile);
            mobjFormat.setSwapBehavior(QSurfaceFormat::DoubleBuffer);
            int intSB = (int)mobjFormat.swapBehavior();
            qDebug() << "swapBehavour as set-up in format: " << QString::number(intSB);
            mpobjContext->setFormat(mobjFormat);
            intSB = (int)mpobjContext->format().swapBehavior();
            qDebug() << "swapBehavour as set-up in context: " << QString::number(intSB);
        }
    }
```

I can see in the debugger that intSB is 2 when checking swap behaviour from the format, but when I check intSB as set in the context it is 0, not 2?

As a result of this anything I render to the context is visible.

Comment: You're attempting to set the format of a context that has already been created.  I don't think that will [work](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglcontext.html#setFormat).  Assuming `clsElevStrip` inherits from `QOpenGLWidget`, try calling [`QOpenGLWidget:;setFormat`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglwidget.html#setFormat) in the `clsElevStrip` constructor.

Comment: This was copied from an online example, if it isn't possible then what's the point of the setFormat method?  QOpenGLWidget::setFormat doesn't allow a context to be supplied, so how could that work?

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglcontext.html#setFormat

Comment: From what I understand the `Qt` framework will create the context with the format returned by [`QOpenGLWidget::format`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglcontext.html#format).  Thus, calling `QOpenGLWidget::setFormat` from the constructor should affect the format used.  Also note that the link you give to `QOpenGLContext::setFormat` states that "You need to call create() before it takes effect".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved:

I modified the code, adding

```
    mpobjContext->create();
```

After:

```
    mpobjContext->setFormat(mobjFormat);
```

Now it works!